# Firebase storage size limits not enforced

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Hello I have rules for the folder /posts/media/{userId}/{media} like the following:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPath=**} {
      allow read, create, write;
    }

    match /posts/media {
        allow create: if request.auth != null && request.resource.size < 10 * 1024 * 1024
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('(image|video)/.*');

      match /{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
        allow create, write: if request.auth.uid == userId && request.resource.size < 10 * 1024 * 1024
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('(image|video)/.*');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The file size of 10MB is not enforced. Users can easily post videos of several times the limit of 10MB.

Any help?

Thank you,
Michel

Comment: Without seeing the code that performs the upload, its not possible to see if your rules and code actually match the way you intend.  We need to be able to see that your code actually uploads files to the location that's protected by security rules.  I suggest first starting out with some very simple rules in order to make sure they trigger as expected, then make them more complex.

Comment: They do, because the file ends up at the spot intended. Except that it accepts files way larger than the limit. The upload works, but it should not accept so large files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rules is allowing unrestricted read and write access to your entire storage bucket:

```
match /{allPath=**} {
  allow read, create, write;
}
```

If you don't want that behavior, then remove that rule.  Its permissiveness is going to override all other rules.  You can't narrow the scope of access granted by another rule.  If any rule allows access to a file, that can't be changed by another rule.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. But if I remove it completely, all access is denied. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Not all, access.  The other rules will kick in at that point.  Setting rules for the entire bucket like this is kind of an anti-pattern.  You should allocate special areas of the bucket (using the path of the files) for special needs.  If you need a full read-write area, make a special path for it.